# After how much time does your comment become un-editable?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How does the comment system and comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-does-the-comment-system-and-comments-work)
>   [Where is the FAQ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33331/where-is-the-faq)

*This is surely answered somewhere, but currently I cannot find it.*

I know your (i.e. mine) comment cannot be edited after someone replies, but if no one replies on them, after how many minutes do they become uneditable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, after 5 minutes the comment becomes un-editable. [See here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-does-the-comment-system-and-comments-work).

Comment: Jon, don't feel like you have to CW things, the CW police aren't active here.  The only CW usually used here is on polls.

Comment: Thanks ! I don't think I saw that one when searching ...

Comment: @Lance: I've seen users in the past CW answers that link to a FAQ question, so I followed that example. This question should be closed anyway.

Comment: @Idigas: No problem. If you think you have a common question, check out questions in the `[faq]` tag.